# Docker swarm did not update service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I use `docker stack deploy` deploy my python service.

First, I edit code.

then

`docker build . -f Dockerfile -t my_service:$TAG`
`docker tag my_service:$TAG register.xxx.com:5000/my_service:$TAG`

When I use `docker run -p 9000:9000 register.xxx.com:5000/my_service:$TAG`

It's worked.

But, when I use `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml my_service_stack`

The service still is running old code.

The part of docker-compose.yaml:

`web:
    image: register.xxx.com:5000/my_service:v0.0.12
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
      - rabbit
    links:
      - redis
      - db
      - rabbit
    volumes:
      - web_service_data:/home
    networks:
      - webnet`

v0.0.12 == $TAG

Dockerfile:

```

FROM python:3.6.4

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash gmt

RUN mkdir -p /home/logs

WORKDIR /home/gmt/src

COPY /src/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/

COPY /src .

RUN cat /home/gmt/src/setting/env.yaml

ENV PYTHONPATH=/home/gmt/src

CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "/home/gmt/src/gunicornconf.py", "run:app"]

```

So, why?

Comment: And exec `docker service ls`, the IMAGE is right.

Comment: ok, I know ,  the question is:  

`volumes:
      - web_service_data:/home`

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see that you actually pushed your image from your build server to your registry. I'll assume you're doing that after build and before deploy.
2. You should not be using a volume for code. That volume will overwrite your /home in the container with the contents of the volume, which are likely stale. Using/storing code in volumes is an anti-pattern.
3. You don't need `links:`, [they are legacy](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/).
4. `depends_on:` is not used in swarm.
5. You should not store logs in the container, you [should have them sent to stdout and stderr](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).

Comment: OK so did I answer your question?  Docker will not continue to "sync" content in an image path to the volume path that overwrites it.